# To print the sum of the numbers(not digits) in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I was recently asked to write a function in java which will sum the numbers(not digits) in a string. e.g. if the string is abc35zz400tt15, the output should be 450.

this is what i wrote :

```
 public static void getSum(String a){
        String[] arr=a.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", arr[i]))
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this as they didn't look satisfied with the above code.

Comment: thanks batty.was my first post :)

Comment: Note that if your strings contain large numbers code using `Integer.parseInt` may throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are look forward efficiency regex matching and object allocations could be overkill for the task. You can scan the string backwards and accumulate the number:

```
int currentPower = 1;
int length = string.length();
int value = 0;

for (int i = string.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
  char curChar = string.charAt(i);
  if (curChar >= '0' && curChar <= '9') {
    value += (curChar - '0') * currentPower;
    currentPower *= 10;
  }
  else
    currentPower = 1;
}
```

Comment: Floris: actually I was going to let such micro-optimizations to the OP but since you pointed out :D

Comment: Alrighty! NOW I like it. Probably much more efficient than regex at this point.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be a bit simpler just to search for the pattern one at a time, rather than split the String.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+"); //or you can use \\d if you want
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);

while(matcher.find()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: @boxed__l: The default radix is 10, and `Integer.parseInt("021")` yields `21` as I'd expect.  There might be many edge cases based on the actual requirements, but since we don't have said requirements I'll leave those for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution, without any usage of Matcher and Pattern:

```
    String line = "abc35zz400tt15";
    int sum = 0;

    String[] numbers = line.split("\\D");
    for (String digit : numbers) {
        if (digit.length() > 0) sum += Integer.valueOf(digit);
    }
```

Comment: No explicit use of Matcher or Pattern, but it's still using regex so it's using Matcher and Pattern behind the scenes :-).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: replace everything that is not a number with a `+` sign, and evaluate the result. That is not very efficient in Java, but there are other instances (`bash` for example) where it would be the right thing to do. So I'm putting that suggestion here "for future visitors".

Clarification: I mean something like

```
echo abc35zz400tt15 | sed -E 's/[^0-9]+/\+/g' | sed 's/^\+//' | bc
```

That is

```
find one or more characters that are not a digit
replace all of them with a +
then strip the first `+` if it's the first character in the line
and evaluate the result
```

The above yields

```
450
```

as expected.

Note - `bc` doesn't like it when the string you feed it starts with a `+` - hence the need for the second `sed`.

Note 2 - the `-E` flag is used on Mac OSX to set "extended regular expressions". This gives special meaning ('one or more') to the `+` character - shorter than `\{1,}\}`... I know the Mac one is subtly different than the `gnu` one, but don't know whether this is one of those occasions.

Comment: I'm not a bash expert.  When I do `RESULT=$(expr +++35++400++15)` and echo `$RESULT` I just get `+++35++400+15`.  Can bash really be expected to get `450` out of that?  If so, how?

Comment: Sorry - I meant "run of non-digits" not "each individual digit". Should have been more explicit.

Comment: @MarkPeters you were right to ask that question - updated my answer with a better explanation (and explicit code).

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy Java 8, you can write it in a fairly expressive way:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\D+"))
             .filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
             .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
             .sum();
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit:: 
Whoops, read too fast, you wanted numbers, not digits. I believe someone has already answered above. I also have answered the question using my original (but incorrect) approach

**Previous Answer**

Look at Java's `isDigit(char c)`. It may look something like:

```
public static void getSum(string a) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

**New answer using an iterative approach**

```
public static void getSum(String a) {
    int sum = 0;
    String num = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
            num = num + a.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if(!num.equals("")) {
                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
                num = "";
            }
        }
    }
    if(!num.equals("")) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I think the question was clear that the OP doesn't want the sum of digits that appear in the string, but rather the numbers.  This is a great way to do it for digits.

Comment: I think this sums the digits - groups of digits need to be summed as a single 'number'.

Comment: You are both correct, I either read too fast or misread the question!

Comment: Happens to all of us. You might want to delete your answer to get rid of the negative reputation points.

Comment: I might leave it up in case someone accidentally ends up here when trying to answer the question I solved. Hell I might try and do it using `isDigit()`

Comment: @JustinC if you look at Jack's answer above, it would benefit from `isDigit` - then it would be the answer you intended to give...